# Intel XDK, change iOS7 status bar color

Tags: intel-xdk

How can I change the background color of the iOS7 statusbar? The statusbar, by default, is black and has white icons and text. I want to change the background color of the statusbar (which shows battery, time, carrier etc...). Who knows how I can do this with Intel XDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Cordova plugin, https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin, it should give you what you need. Note that you must use the Cordova build system to use this feature, there is no way to extend that "legacy" builds. Also, if you have not already, please upgrade to 1199, which makes it much easier to configure and build Cordova based apps.

Comment: Thx a lot. I was just starting to get desparate :)